# Static popping and crackling sound

Tags: drivers, sound

I've been having issues with static noises, popping and crackling, for a while now. They happen briefly when I boot up, but stop on before I log in. They come back at seemingly random times. Browsing the internet seems to be a trigger, or just extended periods of use. Doesn't matter whether the charger is connected or not.

I use the motherboard speakers. The speakers work fine, they play sounds without issue if I ever have them on. The noises occur whether or not the speakers are muted or not or in use.

Not sure if this is a hardware issue or a driver issue or a connection issue, but it is getting really annoying. I've tried most of the "power save" solutions listed for other crackling noise questions on this site to no avail.

Any info would be appreciated, thanks!

Update: I reinstalled windows OS on my SSD and it works fine with none of the noises...I am using an HP Envy Notebook is there any known problems with these laptops?

Comment: To clarify, are these sounds coming from the speakers? Or the hardware itself?

Comment: I believe it is coming from the speakers. More of a static sound than scratching or something physical.

Comment: Sounds like interference. Do you have a mobile phone near them?

Comment: Yes, usually a phone and laptop. Multiple devices in my house have wifi/Bluetooth capability